# Can't run any normal javascript code in node.js express.js

Tags: javascript, express

I am learning express.js and I have this basic express code here:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
})

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    let n1 = req.body.num1 //num1 and num2 are coming from index.html which I have inciude above
    let n2 = req.body.num2

    let result = n1 + n2
    res.send(result)
})
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

But it take n1 and n2 as strings. So if I give n1 = 2 and n2 = 4 it returns 24 but not 6 so I tried to convert n1 and n2 as numbers so I have tried

```
    let n1 = Number(req.body.num1)
    let n2 = Number(req.body.num2)
```

But it gives error called :

```
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 5
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
at ServerResponse.writeHead (node:_http_server:275:11)
at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (node:_http_server:266:8)
at write_ (node:_http_outgoing:766:9)
at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:855:5)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\USERNAME \OneDrive\Desktop\lll\calculator\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:232:10)
at ServerResponse.sendStatus (C:\Users\USERNAME \OneDrive\Desktop\\calculator\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:375:15)
at C:\Users\USERNAME \OneDrive\Desktop\lll\calculator\calculator.js:18:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\USERNAME \OneDrive\Desktop\lll\calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\USERNAME \OneDrive\Desktop\lll\calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
```

Even if I tried to console log the type of `result` it returns this type of error. Can someone help me please

The index.html code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Caluculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Caluculator</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="Enter First Number" />
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Enter Second Number" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you passing correct header (application/json)? And num1/num2 are i nnumber format in body when you are trying to send request to express? (would help if you could also include index.html to code)

Comment: Can you tell me how I can check it

Comment: you can take a look at network tab in browser console, there is your request and in reques body there should be c ontent which you are trying to pass to server, string is with quotes, numbers are just numbers

Comment: Include `index.html` file too.

Comment: I have included it now please check

Comment: I've answered below @Lokesh, your trying to return a status code instead of an actual response.

Answer (score 0):

The error come from this line
res.sendStatus(result)
Result is not a valid statut code.
Instead of

```
let n1 = Number(req.body.num1);
```

Put

```
const n1 = +req.body.num1;
const n2 = +req.body.num2;
const result= n1+n2;
res.status(200).send({result, 
message:"success"});
```

The status code must be from 100 to 599

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix it

Comment: That won't work as only in certain calculations would a valid status code be the result. See my answer below for the fix @Lokesh.

Comment: You want to just send the result or set the status code ?

Comment: To send the result : res.status(200).send(result); after you do the calculation like I said.

Comment: To set the status : res.sendStatus(status). But status must be between 100 and 599

Answer (score 0):

The error does come from `res.sendStatus(result)` and should instead be `res.send(result)`. If you do want to manually set the status, then it should be `res.status(200).send(result)`, exchanging 200 for the status code you want to set.

On top of this, you should also convert the number to a string. The most performant way is debateable, but my usual method of doing so is like `${n1 + n2}`.

In your case, with the changes mentioned above, your JavScript should look like:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
})

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    let n1 = req.body.num1 //num1 and num2 are coming from index.html which I have inciude above
    let n2 = req.body.num2

    let result = n1 + n2
    res.send(`${result}`)
})
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

There's some more information in the [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res).

Comment: Even if I used .send() instead of .sendStatus() it give the same error

Comment: I've added more content to my answer as I also realised you hadn't converted the result to a string. I've left a complete example of what your JS should look like after the changes too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer like this [Unable to send numbers using res.send() using express with node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498601/unable-to-send-numbers-using-res-send-using-express-with-node)

You must send string instead of number

```js
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    let n1 = Number(req.body.num1) //num1 and num2 are coming from index.html which I have inciude above
    let n2 = Number(req.body.num2)

    let result = n1 + n2
    res.send(''+result)
})
```

I tested and it run

Answer (score 0):

```
let n1 = parseInt(req.body.num1);  
let n2 = parseInt(req.body.num2);  
let result = n1 + n2;  
return res.status(200).send({result});
```

You will get an integer value after using `parseInt()`.
also, you can use a `+` sign before variable.

```js
let num1 = "2";  
let num2 = "4";  
let n1 = parseInt(num1);  
let n2 = parseInt(num2);  
let result = n1 + n2;  
console.log('result >>>', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

```
let n1 = req.body.num1
let n2 = req.body.num2
let result = Number(n1) + Number(n2)
res.send("" + result)
```

You have to just add an empty string. I don't know why it works but it worked