# How to do typecasting in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-development-server

While I try to change the string value to number I am facing a error.

```js
const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/" ,function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
})
app.post("/",function(req,res){
    var num1=Number(req.body.num1);
    var num2=Number(req.body.num2);
    var result=num1+num2;
    res.send(result);
})
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("server started");
})
```

When I am using the Number() function [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u15sN.png) is raised.
Can anybody help me with this?

I want the result to be shown in the localhost page

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498665) answer your question?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Response#send` with a number will send that number as the response status code. You have to convert it to a string:

```js
app.post("/",function(req,res){
    var num1=Number(req.body.num1);
    var num2=Number(req.body.num2);
    var result=num1+num2;
    res.send(result.toString());
})
```

[The documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) states that:

> The `body` parameter can be a `Buffer` object, a `String`, an object, `Boolean`, or an `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll probably want to include a line like `app.use(bodyParser.json())` to make accessing data from your request body easier.
For example:

```js
//...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(bodyParser.json()) // add this line

app.get("/" ,function(req,res){
//...
```

The next issue is in your `res.send()` function.
According to [express documentation on this function](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send):

> res.send([body]) - Sends the HTTP response.
>
> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, Boolean, or an Array.

You're sending a number, which isn't supported so weird behavior is occuring. If you change it to a string or an object you should be fine. For example:

```js
//...
  var result=num1+num2;
  res.send({ request });
//...
```

will result in a response like this (if the request gives 1 as `num1` and 2 as `num2`):

```
{
    "result": 8
}
```

I hope that helps!